# 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente error, adjunto la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
var p = "\'+ @Model.ArchivoCSF.NombreArchivo +\'";
var c = "\'+ @Model.ArchivoCSF.Contenido +\'";

if (p != null) {
    $(this).next('a').text(p);
    $(this).next('a').prop("href", URL.createObjectURL(c));
    $(this).next('a').css('display', 'block');
    $("#deleteFile2").css('display', 'block');
    console.log(p);
}
```

Este código es para poder visualizar un nombre de documento previamente cargado, y al editar me deberá mostrar abajo en el input file dicho archivo ya sea para eliminarlo y cargar uno nuevo o simplemente visualizar que documentos se subieron en ese registro.

Agradeceré mucho de sus comentarios y/o referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Según MDN el [objeto pasado por parámetro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static#parameters) debe ser:

> A File, Blob, or MediaSource object to create an object URL for.

Al parecer estas pasando el contenido.

```
var c = "\'+ @Model.ArchivoCSF.Contenido +\'";
```

...

```
$(this).next('a').prop("href", URL.createObjectURL(c));
```

proba creando un objeto de ese tipo, algo así:

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(c, {type: t}))
```

donde `t` será el `content-type` por ejemplo

```
t = "application/pdf";
$(this).next('a').prop(
  "href",
  URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(c, {type: t}))
);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo intenté, pero me salía una excepción por lo del Blob, por lo que mi variable c, la puse de esta forma: $(this).next('a').prop("href", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([c], { type: t })));